# How can I safely pool Redis connections from Python?

Tags: python, redis

The default [ConnectionPool class](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/blob/master/redis/connection.py#L722) for redis-py will never dispose of connections, and the `max_connections` argument will just throw an exception if the limit is hit.

How can I safely pool Redis connections without either artificially limiting the pool size, or keeping an unbounded number of connections held open after a burst?

Comment: You wont leak connections if you return them to the pool with `release` (https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/blob/master/redis/connection.py#L894). Is that what you are asking? I am not sure what the issue you have or what your use case is.

Comment: They will "leak" insomuch as, after a burst, the connections created during the burst will hang around in the pool and never be returned.